# Why is this simple gossip script not working?

Tags: c++, azerothcore

When I am trying to make a gossip NPC with AI, the `sGossipSelect` comes with wrong action id.

If I add a gossip item:

```
AddGossipItemFor(player, GOSSIP_ICON_CHAT, "testone", GOSSIP_SENDER_MAIN, 1);
```

and when the `sGossipSelect` gets triggered it comes with wrong `uint32` action value so it will not work.

Here is my full code:

```
class gossip_test : public CreatureScript
{
public:
    gossip_test() : CreatureScript("gossip_test") { }

    struct gossip_testAI : public ScriptedAI
    {
        gossip_testAI(Creature* creature) : ScriptedAI(creature) {}

        void sGossipHello(Player* player)
        {
            AddGossipItemFor(player, GOSSIP_ICON_CHAT, "testone", GOSSIP_SENDER_MAIN, 1);
            AddGossipItemFor(player, GOSSIP_ICON_CHAT, "testwo", GOSSIP_SENDER_MAIN, 2);
            SendGossipMenuFor(player, DEFAULT_GOSSIP_MESSAGE, me);
        }
        void sGossipSelect(Player* player, uint32 sender, uint32 action)
        {

            // UINT32 ACTION ALAWAYS HAVE WRONG VALUE
            if (action == 1)
            {
                me->MonsterYell("testone, LANG_UNIVERSAL, me);
            }

            if (action == 2)
            {
                me->MonsterYell("testwo, LANG_UNIVERSAL, me);
            }

            ClearGossipMenuFor(player);
            CloseGossipMenuFor(player);
        }

    };

    CreatureAI* GetAI(Creature* creature) const
    {
        return new gossip_testAI(creature);
    }
};
```

Comment: Did you check packet before sending? Does it has proper values?

Comment: I moved the whole gossip thing outside of the AI using those bool hooks, it is working now. It seems the AI is wrong.